# Генерация пилообразного сигнала

Tags: аудио, c++

Написал функцию, заполняющую массив float пилообразной волной заданной частоты. Звучит плохо, особенно высокие частоты. Видимо, это из-за того, что я неправильно учитываю накапливающиеся дробные семплы. Но я не могу придумать, как их правильно учесть?

```
void sawtooth(double upPercent, float volume, float freq,
    uint sampleRate, ArrayRange<float> outSamples)
{
    const uint fullPeriodsCount=(uint)(outSamples.Count()*freq/sampleRate);
    const double samplesPerPeriod=sampleRate/freq;
    const double samplesPerUp=samplesPerPeriod*upPercent;
    const double samplesPerDown=samplesPerPeriod-samplesPerUp;
    const uint intSamplesPerUp=(uint)samplesPerUp;
    const uint intSamplesPerDown=(uint)samplesPerDown;
    const double fractSamplesPerUp=fract(samplesPerUp);
    const double fractSamplesPerDown=fract(samplesPerDown);

    double upFraction=0, downFraction=0;
    uint pos=0;
    double v=-volume, du=2*volume/samplesPerUp, dd=2*volume/samplesPerDown;
    for(uint k=0; k<fullPeriodsCount; k++)
    {
        for(uint s=0; s<intSamplesPerUp; s++)
             outSamples[pos++]=(float)v, v+=du;
        upFraction+=fractSamplesPerUp;
        if(upFraction>=1) {upFraction--; outSamples[pos++]=(float)v; v+=du;}

        for(uint s=0; s<intSamplesPerDown; s++)
            outSamples[pos++]=(float)v, v-=dd;
        downFraction+=fractSamplesPerDown;
        if(downFraction>=1) {downFraction--; outSamples[pos++]=(float)v; v-=dd;}
    }
}
```

Здесь upPercent - это время нарастания, делённое на весь период волны.
 Ещё важно, чтобы эта функция была как можно быстрее. У меня есть корректная реализация, но она в 6 раз медленнее работает, чем эта но неправильная.

Comment: а давайте посмотрим вашу правильную реализацию и попробуем посмотреть что там можно оптимизировать? А заодно и сравним с этой.

Comment: Если я все правильно разобрал, то у вас не пила, у вас треугольник. В треугольнике вообще с высокими все беднее, не говоря уж о другом строении спектра (пила - все гармоники, треугольник - только нечетные). У вас сигнал сначала нарастает, потом падает, в пиле он либо нарастает и молниеносно падает, либо, наоборот, падает, а затем молниеносно возрастает (для справки скажу, что в отсутствие искажений интерференционного толка уху наплевать на направление).
[кпз из вики](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Waveforms.svg/780px-Waveforms.svg.png)

Comment: Правильная реализация использует кучу операций на семпл, потому что она работает как функция от времени, там нечего оптимизировать. Для последовательного вычисления быстрее намного делать через приращения, что я и попытался сделать. Но из-за того, что на нарастание и спад иногда меньше одно семпла приходится, то звук сильно искажается.
 Нет, у меня обобщенная пила. Если updownPercent равен 0, то это пила, состоящая только из спадов. Если 1, то - только из нарастаний. Если равен 0.5, то это симметричный треугольник. В остальных случаях это несимметричные треугольники.

Comment: @GLmonster

> Но из-за того, что на нарастание и спад иногда меньше одно семпла приходится, то звук сильно искажается.

Как вы это определели? По теореме Котельникова там вообще искажений слышно не будет.

Comment: Я пробовал по-разному учитывать дробные семплы, и получал разный звук. Различия усиливались при увеличении частоты волны или при уменьшении частоты дискретизации.
 У меня получалось, что samplesPerUp равно 0.89, то есть меньше 1, и ничего даже похожего на нарастание не получалось, волна искривлялась непонятно как.

Comment: А не пробовали как-то сигнал визуализировать, чтобы понять, какая программа дает сигнал нужной формы? Я в свое время готовил заголовок и сэмплы для проигрывания через PlaySound, для тестирования записывал весь буфер вместе с заголовком в файл wav и просматривал его через Audacity.

Comment: Я как раз подумывал об этом. Прям точно так же думал записать в wav и его открывать в Audacity. Но я в принципе и так видел, в чём проблема, и это было не нужно. Семплы располагались неравномерно и из-за этого были сильные искажения. Мне удалось свести их к минимуму, но я всё равно представляю, почему они могут возникать, но не знаю, что с этим делать.

Answer (score 1):

Методом размышлений, проб и ошибок пришёл к такому:

```
double fraction=fractSamplesPerDown/2;
//Цикл ниже начинается от минимального значения сигнала, а нам нужно начать с нулевого, чтобы не было скачка. Сделаем половину спада перед циклом
for(uint s=1; s<samplesPerDown/2; s++) inOutSamples[pos++]=(float)v, v-=dd;
v=-volume;

for(int k=0; k<fullPeriodsCount; k++)
{
    //Нарастание
    for(uint s=0; s<intSamplesPerUp; s++)
        inOutSamples[pos++]=(float)v, v+=du;
    fraction+=fractSamplesPerUp;
    if(fraction>=1) fraction--, inOutSamples[pos++]=(float)v;
    v=volume;

    //Спад
    for(uint s=0; s<intSamplesPerDown; s++)
        inOutSamples[pos++]=(float)v, v-=dd;
    fraction+=fractSamplesPerDown;
    if(fraction>=1) fraction--, inOutSamples[pos++]=(float)v;
    v=-volume;
}
```

При частоте дискретизации 11 кГц звучит похоже на мою предыдущую реализацию, но все равно звук не совсем чистый. Но повышение производительности в 7 раз с лихвой окупило переход на 48 кГц, а на такой частоте уже всё нормально. Так что принципе меня этот вариант устраивает, но если вдруг у кого появятся идеи, как сделать ещё лучше, то пишите.
 Естественно, этот код ещё можно будет потом оптимизировать, я ещё к этому даже не приступал.

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь пригодится, а то сам я нигде не мог найти этого алгоритма.

Comment: На 11 кГц нет частот выше 5.5 кГц, там по умолчанию должно звучать, как через стену.  
Вообще проще всего ориентироваться на результирующую уровнеграмму из какого-нибудь audition.

Comment: Это понятно, но предыдущий вариант на 11 кГц звучал лучше, чем этот на 11 кГц, это факт. Но так как я перешёл аж на 48 кГц, то в принципе это неважно, так как на этой частоте искажения становятся пренебрежимо малыми.